# Proving the contrapositive statements

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I have successfully proved $a^2 < b^2$ if $0 \leq a<b$, where a,b are real numbers

But I am struggling to prove the contrapositive of this statement i.e.
$|a|<|b|$ , if and only if $a^2<b^2$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean the converse?  A statement and its contrapositive are equivalent.

Comment: Yes, I might be confused by the jargon here. But yes, I am pretty much looking to prove the converse.
Basically I want to prove this
$|a|<|b| $ , if and only if $a^2<b^2$
if a, b are real numbers

Comment: Have you tried proving it by contradiction?

Comment: Not exactly sure, how to prove it by contradiction. Can you provide any starter/hint? Would appreciate that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINTS**

Assume that $a^2<b^2.$  There are three possibilities:

$$
|a|>|b|\\
|a|=|b|\\
|a|<|b|
$$
If you assume either of the first two, you will get at contradiction, so the third must be the case.

Comment: Okay, got it, Thanks!

Comment: If this answers your question, you should accept it by clicking the check mark.  That way, everyone can see that the question has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

$P\implies Q$ will be true if and only if $\lnot Q \implies \lnot P$.

So to prove $|a| < |b| \implies a^2 < b^2$ is straightforward and you claimed you did it.

I'd do it as $0 \le |a| < |b|$  and if $|a| = 0$ this is trivial.  $|b^2| > 0$ so $|b^2| > 0 =|a^2|$.  And if $0 < |a| < |b|$ then  $a^2 = |a|*|a| < |b|*|a|$ and $|b|*|a|< |b|*|b|=b^2$ so $a^2 < b^2$.

To prove $a^2 < b^2 \implies |a| < |b|$ it'd suffice to prove:

$\lnot (|a| < |b|) \implies \lnot(a^2 < b^2)$ or in other words:

$|a| \ge |b| \implies b^2 \ge a^2$ or in still other words $|b|\le |a| \implies b^2 \le a^2$.

But you pretty much did that already.  If $0 \le |b| < |a| $ then $b^2 < a^2$ as we proved above.  And if $|b| =|a|$ then $b^2 = a^2$.  So $b^2 \le a^2$.

And that's it.  We're done.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks!